# I have large nodes of data 9000+ on firebase realtime database, I want to delete all except a few nodes

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an application for pharmacies, all the data are on realtime database like: users information, chat and cart.
I accidentally imported json file of the drugs on the main node of the application now I have 9000+ node and I can't delete them manually.
I want to delete them all except 4 nodes  or to undo my last action.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach I can think of is to:

1. Load the values you want to keep.
2. Create a `Map<String, Object>` with those values.
3. Then pass the map to `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().setValue(valuesMap)`.